# Laravel routes with entrust

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I try to Entrust in my Laravel code.
At this moment I have users, permisions and roles.

create admin panel where you want to access the "permissions" == "admin - panel"

I wish it was done by the file routes.php

My files:
Middleware/EntrustMiddleware.php

```
class EntrustMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Entrust::can('admin-panel')) {
        return Redirect::to('home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('admin-panel', ['middleware' => ['auth', 'Entrust'], function () {

}]);
```

I have tried many methods , but still does not work. Can anyone suggest how to set file " routes.php " to access the " admin - panel / 'was only when "permissions" == "admin-panel"

--Edit--

When i'm using this method i get error:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['Entrust']], function () {
    //put your routes here
    Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController@index');
});
```

ErrorException in Pipeline.php line 136: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade' does not have a method 'handle'

--edit2--

```
['middleware' => ['permission:NAME']]
```

Now I understand :)

Is Contoller I have to add some extra security or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `entrust`, for all those `routes` which you want to allow access for specific `roles`, you just need to put it in group, that will do the job, being said that, here's how it will look like,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['add roles name here']], function () {
  //put your routes here
});
```

Comment: Edited the question , can you see them?

Comment: I should add something to the Controller or not ?

Comment: you don't need to add anything in the controller